# Even when I use sleep() in parent process my child process is executed last

Tags: c, process, parallel-processing, fork, sleep

can somebody explain why the parent process is always finished completely before the while loop in the child process is started even if I let the parent sleep.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 10000, pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        while(i > 50) {
            if(i%100==0) {
                sleep(20);
            }
            printf("Child: %d\n", i);
            i--;
        }
    } else {
        while(i < 15000) {
            if(i%50==0) {
                sleep(50);
            }
            printf("Parent: %d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Parent: ..
Parent: ..
Parent: ..
```

until Parent is finished, then the same for Child.

Can the reason be that I'm testing on a single core CPU? Would the result change if I had a multi core setup? The sleep(50) is definitely working - since it takes ages until the script is finished - why does the CPU not switch the processes? Are there situations like for example during a while loop where the process has "more" or exclusive rights to the CPU?

Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Changed sleep(50) to sleep(30) if somebody wants to copy/paste the code. sleep(50) takes awfully long for me. I'm editing it in a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are there situations like for example during a while loop where the process has "more" or exclusive rights to the CPU?

Well, that's not defined, but it would be insane.

I can't reproduce your problem. Reducing the sleep times to `2` and `5` seconds (so I don't have to wait forever), the *child* gets unblocked first here, as one would expect. (Debian 8, Linux 3.16.1-ck1 [BFS scheduler, non-standard] on AMD64)

I'd say your scheduler behaves very weird and *might* be just broken. But that being said, it's never a good idea to rely on **any** specific behavior of a scheduler. Always assume it's broken and insane as hell -- if your code allows a specific sequence of execution, there **will** be a scheduler insane enough to choose it.(*)

Therefore, use synchronization primitives (`semaphores` and `mutexes` for example have *shared* versions for usage with different processes -- you could also just use `pipes` in some scenarios) whenever you need to rely on some synchronization.

**edit**: adding two examples for synchronizing the processes.

First a version (ab)using `pipe`s:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 10000;
    int parent_done[2];
    int child_done[2];
    char dummy[1] = { 0 };
    int pid;

    pipe(parent_done);
    pipe(child_done);

    /* stdio buffering would lead to intermingled output */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(parent_done[1]);
        close(child_done[0]);

        while(i > 50) {
            if(i%100==0) {
                if (i < 10000) write(child_done[1], dummy, 1);
                read(parent_done[0], dummy, 1);
            }
            printf("Child: %d\n", i);
            i--;
        }
    } else {
        close(parent_done[0]);
        close(child_done[1]);

        while(i < 15000) {
            if(i%50==0) {
                write(parent_done[1], dummy, 1);
                read(child_done[0], dummy, 1);
            }
            printf("Parent: %d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Then the same using POSIX semaphores (which is IMHO much cleaner because semaphores are *meant* to be used for synchronization):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct semaphores
{
    sem_t child_done;
    sem_t parent_done;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int i = 10000;
    int pid;

    /* map shared memory for the semaphores */
    struct semaphores *sems = mmap(0, sizeof(*sems), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
            MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

    /* initialize both semaphores as "shared" and with an initial count
     * of 0 */
    sem_init(&sems->parent_done, 1, 0);
    sem_init(&sems->child_done, 1, 0);

    /* stdio buffering would lead to intermingled output */
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IONBF, 0);

    pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        while(i > 50) {
            if(i%100==0) {
                if (i < 10000) sem_post(&sems->child_done);
                sem_wait(&sems->parent_done);
            }
            printf("Child: %d\n", i);
            i--;
        }
        sem_post(&sems->child_done);
    } else {
        while(i < 15000) {
            if(i%50==0) {
                sem_post(&sems->parent_done);
                sem_wait(&sems->child_done);
            }
            printf("Parent: %d\n", i);
            i++;
        }
        sem_post(&sems->parent_done);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Windows has a different API for semaphores, see [Semaphore Objects on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx)

(*) **edit2** fits here: While creating the examples, I noticed `stdio` buffering gets in the way without sleeping. So maybe it's not even your scheduler behaving badly but just an implementation of `stdio` with *very* unpredictable behavior on *when* to flush buffers. That's just wild guessing of course. What you have to know is: All `FILE` handles in C are buffered by the `stdio` part of the C library. This includes the predefined `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` handles. Consequence is that what you see in your output doesn't necessarily reflect the sequence in which different threads or processes created that output. Unless, of course, you disable buffering completely like done in my example snippets.

Comment: @chh I added some example code ... but not for windows, too lazy for that now (although the version using pipes might work, not sure right now whether `msvcrt` provides a standard `pipe()` call)

Comment: @chh and now added another possible cause of the counter-intuitive behavior you first experienced.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: lol, I looked for ages at OP code and could not see any major problems with it.  I don't know why it would behave 'oddly' either:(

Comment: @MartinJames the possible "gotcha" with `stdio` buffering also wasn't obvious to me when first looking at the code, I only saw it happening when first creating a properly synchronized version :). But seeing `sleep()` used with the expectation of a particular sequence of execution is always wrong, even if it will work in 99.99% of all scenarios.